# Pass arguments from a button click to Jquery event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to pass the argument to the JQuery event handler when a button is being clicked. In plain JavaScript i was using `onclick="function(argument)"` 
Now i am transferring all of my inline click events to external call like one with Jquery i.e

```
 $(".selector").click(function(){
//some code
});
```

However, in this case i am confused how i can pass the arguments from the HTML tag and how should i receive the arguments in the Jquery event handler.
Please help.

Comment: can you please share the html and show which argument you want to pass

Comment: Can you add a complete example of your Javascript function? It could help answerers to convert it to a Jquery function

Answer (score 2):

An optional object of data passed to an event method when the current executing handler is bound.

In your case it will be something like this -

```
$(".selector").on("click", function(event){
    //you can access the parameter value as follows
    console.log(event.target.value);
});
```

Refer the official documentation here [Pass arguments from a button click to Jquery event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48313297/pass-arguments-from-a-button-click-to-jquery-event-handler)

Comment: replaced to `event.target.value` even `$(this).value()` would work

Answer (score 1):

The `.click()` function receives an `EventData` object that gets passed as the first argument to the handler, you can use that object inside the handler.

For example:

```
$('.selector').click(function(data) {
  $(data).addClass('newClass');
});
```

If you are trying to pass data from the HTML the cleanest way might be to store that data into the `data` attribute of your tag.

The HTML

```
<div id="mydiv" data-arg="Hello world!">Click me</div>
```

The JS

```
$('#mydiv').click(function(data) {
  var arg = $(data).attr('data-arg');
  console.log(arg);
});
```

For what you are trying to achieve

The HTML

```
<button id="dark" data-stroke-width="0.5" 
  class="txtcolor uk-button" type="button">1px</button>
```

The JS

```
$('button#dark').click(function(data) {
  selectStroke($(data).attr('data-stroke-width'));
});
```

Check the [documentation for click](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: Do that EventData will handle the argument value which is being passed from the onclick event. Also, how should i pass that data from the html tag?

Comment: Thanks for the edited response. I have also edited my question too. The second part of the question is how should i pass the value/argument from the HTML to Jquery EventHandler?

Comment: Could you expand your question to show exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: <button id="dark"  onclick="selectStroke(0.5)" class="txtcolor uk-button" type="button">1px</button> this is original HTML code and noe i want to get rid of  inline onclick event. However, want the same functionality

Comment: @Victor, did any of the answers work for you? If so you could accept one?

Answer (score 0):

A sample:

```
// say your selector and click handler looks something like this...
$("some selector").click({param1: "Hello", param2: "World"}, cool_function);

// in your function, just grab the event object and go crazy...
function cool_function(event){
    alert(event.data.param1);
    alert(event.data.param2);
}

var param_obj = {data : {param1: "Hello", param2: "World"}};
cool_function(param_obj);


$("dark").click({param1: 0.5}, selectStroke);
```

or

```
var i = 0.5;
$("dark").click({param1: i}, selectStroke);
```

or if you do not want change functionality of the handler

```
var i = 0.5;
$("dark").click({param1: i}, function() {
    selectStroke(event.data.param1);
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, this is an example of predefined parameters. The question is how to pass the values/arguments dynamically from the HTML and process them in JQuery?

Comment: This is not how you pass the data from HTML button click dynamically. This was my original HTML code. <button id="dark"  onclick="selectStroke(0.5)" class="txtcolor uk-button" type="button">1px</button> Now, i want to get rid of the inline onclick event. However, want to keep the same functionality

Comment: Who distracts you from doing this:
`$("dark").click({param1: 0.5}, selectStroke);`

or 
`var i = 0.5;
$("dark").click({param1: i}, selectStroke);`